# Format a BigDecimal as String with max 2 decimal digits, removing 0 on decimal part

Tags: java, formatting, bigdecimal

I have a BigDecimal number and i consider only 2 decimal places of it so i truncate it using:

```
bd = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN)
```

Now I want to print it as String but removing the decimal part if it is 0, for example:

1.00 -> 1

1.50 -> 1.5

1.99 -> 1.99

I tried using a Formatter, formatter.format but i always get the 2 decimal digits.

How can I do this? Maybe working on the string from bd.toPlainString()?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

I used `DecimalFormat` for formatting the `BigDecimal` instead of formatting the `String`, seems no problems with it.

The code is something like this:

```
bd = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
            
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
            
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
            
df.setGroupingUsed(false);

String result = df.format(bd);
```

Comment: What is the expected output for this program.
I got the same requirements to trailing zeros after decimal pointbut trailing zeros like **.00** truncating in output.

Comment: @ParameshKorrakuti
`df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2)` works fine without the setScale and setGrouping and setMaxFrac.

Comment: Decimal Format is NumberFormat in disguise. Use `NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();` then `numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);` then `String percent = numberFormat.format(yourBigDecimal);`

Comment: Java 9 and up `BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN` is deprecated . Use `RoundingMode.DOWN` instead.

Answer (score 83):

```
new DecimalFormat("#0.##").format(bd)
```

Comment: I use `new DecimalFormat("0.00")` if I want to ensure that the two decimal places are always shown, e.g. `1000.5` will display as `1000.50`.

Comment: @ChrisParton's solution works perfectly, in addition to that if some one require to apply localization, we can use the below logic.

`import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.*;


public class LocalizeExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("123.10");
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
        decimalFormat.applyPattern("#0.00");
        String result = decimalFormat.format(bd);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}`

Answer (score 16):

The below code may help you.

```
protected String getLocalizedBigDecimalValue(BigDecimal input, Locale locale) {
    final NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
    numberFormat.setGroupingUsed(true);
    numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    return numberFormat.format(input);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Use `stripTrailingZeros()`.

[This](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-bigdecimal/striptrailingzer.shtml) article should help you.

Answer (score 4):

If its money use:

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(java.util.Locale.US).format(bd)
```

Comment: NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US) instead