# How to round BigDecimal to return two decimal

Tags: java, android, bigdecimal

I need to return **BigDecimal** in this format (%.##)
For example i have this floating number

```
3.2->3.20
6.2->6.20
112.0->112.00
```

I'm trying this

```
BigDecimal precoDecial = new BigDecimal(preco);
precoDecial.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

But it is not working for me; this returns:

```
for:
3.2->3.2000000476837158203125
6.2->6.2
```

My log with the code reference
 [image]

Comment: try converting to a double, then using a formatter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806278/double-decimal-formatting-in-java

Comment: How are you printing it?

Comment: @ScaryWombat i'm using the log just test what i receive of return

Comment: @ToriJ i need use the data "BigDecimal" :/

Comment: SetScale returns a *new* BigDecimal, it does not modify `precoDecial`. So you should assign the result of `setScale` to a BigDecimal, possibly even `precoDecial`, again.

Answer (score 1):

```
BigDecimal precoDecial = new BigDecimal(1.0);
        precoDecial = precoDecial.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        System.out.println(precoDecial);
```

I tried this in my IDE it worked better give it a try hope my work may solve your problem

output

```
if 1-->1.00
if 1.0-->1.00
if 1.00000000-->1.00
```

Comment: can you say what are values in resultado

Comment: Is an data array with model, i get this from my server

Comment: any sample data like 45.55

Comment: can you be more specific

Comment: I receive a float number like 3.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103667/discussion-between-smashcode-and-helio-soares-junior).

Comment: @Helio, I think the problem here is that BigDecimal instances are immutable. `precoDecial.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);` doesn't change precoDecial state, you should do something like `precoDecial = precoDecial.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);`

Comment: Another comment here is that if you just want to print it or convert it to a String this approach should be better: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269045/format-a-bigdecimal-as-string-with-max-2-decimal-digits-removing-0-on-decimal-p]

Comment: @WagnerTsuchiya tank you *-* i not repared this *-* but i used this:

Comment: `precoDecial.round(new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)`

Comment: @Helio: it worked, but it would have worked without the call to `round()` as well. The real problem is what Wagner wrote: `setScale` does not modify the BigDecimal it is called on, it returns a new BigDecimal with the desired value.